# Cannot login. What is wrong in the code below?

Tags: php, mysql

Got the template from web and edited according to my database. I am using xampp to test this. Although I can register with the register.php but cannot login. I think there is something wrong in the code of login.php. Can someone point out the problem?
Thank you.

register.php

```
  <?php 

require('config.php');
$error="";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])=="Sign up") {
  if(!$_POST['name'])  $error.="<br/>Please enter your name";
if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br/>Please enter your email";
else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.=" <br/>Please enter a valid email address" ;
if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br/>Please enter your password";
    else{
if(strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.= "<br/>Please enter a password with atleast 8 charachters";
if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST["password"])) $error.="<br/>Please include atleast one capital letter in your password";
        }
if ($error) echo "There were error(s) in your signup details:" .$error;
else{
$query= "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email'])."'";
    $match= mysqli_query($link,$query); 
    $results= mysqli_num_rows($match);
    if ($results) echo "That email address is already registered. Do you  want to log in ?";
    else {
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['email']);
   $password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $query= "INSERT INTO `members`(name,email,password)     VALUES('$name','$email','".$password."')";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
          if($result){
     echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>You are registered successfully.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }



       }
   }
}



else{

?>

<form method="post">
<h1>Registration</h1><br>
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" /><br>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" /><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up" /><br>


</form>

<?php } ?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 


require("config.php");

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])=="Login"){
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
   $password = password_hash($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query= "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='$name' AND password='".$password."'";

$result= mysqli_query($link,$query)  or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
     if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

    header("Location: profile.php");
         }else{
 echo "<div class='form'>
<h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
<br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
}


}
else{
?>
<form method="post">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="name" name="name" /><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='register.php'>Register Here</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

UPDATE

```
<?php   
session_start();

require("config.php");


if ( isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print_r($_POST);
    $name       = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
    $password   = md5($_POST['password']);
    echo $password; 
    echo $name;
    $query      = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE name='shohan' AND password='f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8'";      
    $result     = mysqli_query($link, $query)  or die(mysqli_error($link)) ;
    $rows       = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo($rows);

    if ($rows) {                
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
            $_SESSION['id']     = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['name']   = $row['name'];
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            break;
        }           
        header("Location: profile.php");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "<div class='form'>
            <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
            <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
}

?>
<form method="post">
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="name" name="name" /><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='register.php'>Register Here</a></p>
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is going wrong? Is there an error of some sort?

Comment: It says invalid username and password. Although I am entering the same one that I used in registering.

Comment: also check mysqli errors not `mysql_error()`, u also need to change this `isset($_POST['submit'])=="Login"`

Comment: echo $query variable and paste that in sql db and check it is returning record or not..

Comment: in last instead of using `if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {` TRY, `if ($rows > 0) {`

Comment: @SanojSharma I did that, it is returning record. It's not empty.

Comment: $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);  
if ($rows > 0) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

    header("Location: profile.php");
         }

Comment: Try the updated code in the Post below. That could do the trick for you....

Answer (score 2):

The Major Problem is this line of code: `isset($_POST['submit'])=="Login"` This Line essentially says: **if(true == "Login")** or  **if(false == "Login")**. This is because  `isset($_POST['submit'])` evaluates to a Boolean `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So the part: `=="Login"` should be removed, leaving you with only:  `isset($_POST['submit'])`

> On the other hand; there are a few things you might need to note: First, ***You should be careful, using Raw Passwords in your Applications***. Passwords are far much secure when encrypted. Second, ***using variables from form directly in your SQL Queries is so much of a risk*** (after all you are using mysqli). Third: ***whenever you are dealing with sessions, always make sure you `session_start()` comes first***. The Code Snippet in this Code is similar to yours with just minor tweaks. The Query is the same (however, you should looki into it yourself based on the points mentioned above).

**LOGIN.PHP**

```
<?php   
    session_start();

    require("config.php");



    if ( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name    = isset($_POST['name'])     ? htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])))     : "";
        $rawPass = isset($_POST['password']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['password']))) : "";

        // BAD PRACTICE: WHERE name='$name' 
        $query   = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='$name'";
        $res     = mysqli_query($link, $query1);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            // GET THE STORED PASSWORD FOR EACH USER WITH NAME = $name
            $pass = $row['password'];

            // VERIFY THAT THE PASSWORD IS CORRECT
            // AND THEN SIMPLY STORED HIS DATA TO THE SESSION AND BREAK OFF THE LOOP:
            if (password_verify($rawPass, $pass)) {
                $_SESSION['id']   = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

                // REDIRECT TO PROFILE PAGE AND EXIT;
                header("Location: profile.php");
                exit;
            }
        }

        echo "<div class='form'>
              <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
              <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }

?>
<form method="post">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="name" name="name" /><br>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='register.php'>Register Here</a></p>
```

**UPDATE::**

You may need to add a function to verify the password and change your sql as shown below.

```
<?php

    if ( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name    = isset($_POST['name'])     ? htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name'])))     : "";
        $rawPass = isset($_POST['password']) ? htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['password']))) : "";
        $query   = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='$name'";
        $result  = mysqli_query($link, $query);


        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            // GET THE STORED PASSWORD FOR EACH USER WITH NAME = $name
            $pass = $row['password'];

            // VERIFY THAT THE PASSWORD IS CORRECT
            // AND THEN SIMPLY STORED HIS DATA TO THE SESSION AND BREAK OFF THE LOOP:  
            if( password_verify($rawPass, $pass) ) {
                $_SESSION['id']   = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

                // REDIRECT TO PROFILE PAGE AND EXIT;
                header("Location: profile.php");
                exit;
            }
        }

        echo "<div class='form'>
              <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
              <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
```

Comment: `mysql_error()` ???

Comment: If that was the problem then he wouldn't get the error of username/password is incorrect right?

Comment: @kerv: same thinking.. check second comment plz

Comment: Not woking. Same error username/password is incorrect.

Comment: @user6827401     Post updated.....Try it again....

Comment: @user6827401: u just need to check either num_rows return something or not..

Comment: @user6827401: now this code will work, try now.

Comment: It still giving error.

Comment: @user6827401       Can you post the Error?

Comment: Same error: username/password is incorrect

Comment: `echo $rows` getting result or not?

Comment: @user6827401       That is another Problem altogether. The password or username must have been wrong... however it is also good to sanitize user-inputs. The Post will now be updated to take that into consideration....

Comment: and last thing, u have signup and login form together? in one file?

Comment: @devpro     your pro-active contributions to this post were not ignored. they were rather truly appreciated - albeit, silently...just so you know..... ;-)

Comment: @Poiz: now waiting for OP response :)

Comment: @devpro Thanks... really...  :-)

Comment: @devpro  No the two forms are different files. register.php and login.php

and echo ($rows) is giving 0.

Comment: than use `print_r($_POST)` after `if ( isset($_POST['submit'])){` AND `echo $password; echo $name` before query. SHARE THE RESULT @Syed

Comment: @devpro     
Array ( [name] => shohan [password] => S12345678 [submit] => Login ) $2y$10$rgf8.Op9FFQYEmaWN/cNKeWkhM8XKBLHJrltvLv7vsFXjH6oBPhDSshohan0

Comment: @Syed     And how is the password stored in your DB? is it stored as raw pass or as hashed-pass like the one shown above?  since `$rows` returned `0`, it just means that somehow, the password and the username doesn't match what was stored in the db.... otherwise `$rows` at the least should have been `1`

Comment: @devpro    In db the password is hashed with password_hash().
I guess the problem is with the hashing. Although I am entering the same password the hashed pass is different. Can it be the case? 
I tried logging with the same passwrd twice it echoed different hashed pass.

Comment: well, just enter this password in database: `S12345678` and remove `password_hash()` just for testing @Syed

Comment: yes u are right, run this query in php myadmin `SELECT MD5('S12345678');` this will return password in `f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8` than just use `md5()` for password field.. after this u must need to change it in register file also @syed.

Comment: like this? (in login.php)

 $name       = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['name']);
        $password   = md5($_POST['password']);
        echo $password; 
        echo $name;
        // BAD PRACTICE: WHERE name='$name' AND password='$password."'";      
        $query      = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='$name' AND password='.$password.'";        
        $result     = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $rows       = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo($rows);

Comment: yes, u r right, but also change the password in database.. `f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8` and same modification required in signup page. @Syed

Comment: changed in db. Now its showing:

Array ( [name] => shohan [password] => S12345678 [submit] => Login ) f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8shohan0

Comment: @syed: `SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE name='shohan' AND password='f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8'` RUN THIS IN PHP MY ADMIN

Comment: @devpro  It returned the row in php my admin.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM members` WHERE name='shohan' AND password='f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8'"` use this, just for testing in your code.

Comment: @devpro   
Array ( [name] => shohan [password] => S12345678 [submit] => Login ) f50db83c94e1e725476295c6ee97d4b8shohan
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: @Syed: can u please update the code in your question.. UPDATE.. dont change original question just add an update

Comment: @devpro   I have edited and updated the post. Now its not showing any errors but when I click login nothing happens.

Comment: @Syed: make sure, connection is fine?

Comment: I am using xampp. Both apache and mysql are running. I refreshed the page and tried again still no response.

Comment: i have checked, your code is working fine on my end @Syed

Comment: @devpro then what could be the problem in my end? can u suggest?

Comment: @Syed: did u checked Poiz code? updated code

Comment: @Syed: what i did, remove `config.php` and add this connection code in same file. `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "yourDB");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}`

Comment: @devpro Yea tried that still same problem. Nothing happens when I click login.

Comment: @Syed: add php error_reporting in your file at top. check errors

Comment: @devpro No errors.